# CSR for Ngnix + Apache Server both naked and www domain

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl, openssl, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to secure  both **naked and www domain** ( https://example.com and https://www.example.com ) with positivessl

1. For this Server cmd would be

   openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example.com.key -out example.com.csr

or it would be something else ?

2. To secure both naked and www domain when server ask for Common Name: What should we put ? 
   example.com or *example.com

Server is Ubuntu 18.04 and Ngnix + Apache 
Thanks

Comment: use the wildcard approach and increase your key size `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out star_friendscom.csr -keyout star_friends.com.key -subj "/C=GH/ST=Greater-Accra/L=Accra/O=Friends LTD./CN=*.friends.com"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close:
use the wildcard approach and increase your key size

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out star_friends.com.csr -keyout star_friends.com.key -subj "/C=GH/ST=Greater-Accra/L=Accra/O=Friends LTD./CN=*.friends.com"
```

Comment: The subject of a certificate should be in the _Subject Alternative Name_ extension these days, not in (or in addition to) the _Subject_ field.  A certificate generated with this would cause Chrome and Firefox to complain.

Comment: @saviour123 Thanks for answer i run command after command it show nothing on screen how can i access the Both Csr and private file

Comment: they are located in location where you run the command, like outputs

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with the following (modified to suit your names) and save it as (for example) `example.cnf` in your chosen directory:

```
[ req ]

prompt             = no
string_mask        = default

# The size of the keys in bits:
default_bits       = 2048
distinguished_name = req_dn
req_extensions     = req_ext

[ req_dn ]

# Note that the following are in 'reverse order' to what you'd expect to see in
# Windows and the numbering is irrelevant as long as each line's number differs.

# Domain Components style:
# Server name:
# 2.DC = com
# 1.DC = example
# commonName = Acme Web Server

# Locality style:
# countryName = GB
# stateOrProvinceName = London
# localityName = Letsby Avenue
# organizationName = Acme
# 1.organizationalUnitName = IT Dept
# 2.organizationalUnitName = Web Services
# commonName = Acme Web Server

# Or traditional org style:
countryName = GB
organizationName = Acme
1.organizationalUnitName = IT Dept
2.organizationalUnitName = Web Services
commonName = Acme Web Server
# Or:    
# commonName = www.example.com

[ req_ext ]

subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
# To automatically copy the CN (in the case of a DNS name in the CN) use:
# DNS.1 = ${req_dn::commonName}
DNS.1 = www.example.com
DNS.2 = example.com
```

Run the following to create your CSR:

```
openssl req -nodes -new -keyout example.key -out example.csr -config example.cnf
```

Note that this leaves the private key in plain-text on your system.  Depending on what service you're using this key with, you might want to consider password protecting it by removing the `-nodes` verb from the command.